# What is the L for in wcout<<L?

Tags: c++, unicode, cout, wstring

What is the difference between

```
std::wcout << "some text" ;
```

and

```
std::wcout <<L "some text";
```

?

I couldn't find information on what the `L` is used for.

Answer (score 6):

The `L` doesn't belong to the `wcout` but to the [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

See from the reference linked above

> 2) Wide string literal. The type of a L"..." string literal is `const wchar_t[]`

Answer (score 2):

`L "blah blah"` is a wide string literal (`const wchar_t[]`), hence why you're using `wcout` rather than `cout`.